# HTML table - convert each column into accordion on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a table which has the first column as the months of the year.

There are four other columns - when the device breaks 768px and below, I want to turn each of the four columns into an accordion with the column heading as the accordion name. Each accordion contains a two column table, the months of the year and the values

[image: Browser table]

So when the mobile device view is triggered, the user sees an accordion with the heading "Monthy earnings" and within that accordion

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>200</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>240</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's really an impossible question - there isn't one way to do this, you could do this (maybe) just with CSS or maybe with Javascript .. or lots of other solutions - without creating a solution for you myself I couldn't 'solve' your question.

You might want to check out this which might give you some ideas on how to achieve what you're after and I'd say it's a really good starting point to solving your question:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

You can read up all about it here

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution may be to include a CSS framework like [Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/) or [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) that already have collapsible component and create an accordion separate from the table with the same information. You can then use CSS media queries to toggle your accordion & tables visibility at a given breakpoint.

For example:

```
@media (min-width:768px){
        .my-accordion{
              display: none; //hides the accordion when the display is greater than 768px
         }
 }
```

The mentioned frameworks also have solutions for responsive tables.